# sql for update "ERROR: column "used" of relation "account" does not exist" even though it does

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have used this method without using the join in the query and it was working as expected. But I added a inner join and now it can't update the "used" column

```
  public HashMap<String, Comparable> getPhoneNumberAndMarkAsUsed() {
    String[] colNames = { "phone_number.id", "phone_number.phone_number",
        "phone_number.account_id", "phone_number.used AS used",
        "(now() AT TIME ZONE account.timezone)::time AS local_time" };
    String query = "select " + Stream.of(colNames).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
        + " from account INNER JOIN phone_number ON account.id = phone_number.account_id where phone_number.used = false order by id DESC limit 1 for update";

    HashMap<String, Comparable> account = new HashMap<String, Comparable>();

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props); // Make sure conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
      conn.setAutoCommit(false);

      ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
      int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
      while (rs.next()) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
          if (i > 1)
            System.out.print(",  ");
          String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
          System.out.print(columnValue + " " + rsmd.getColumnName(i));
        }

        // Get the current values, if you need them.
        account.put("phone_number", rs.getString("phone_number"));
        account.put("account_id", rs.getLong("account_id"));

        rs.updateBoolean("used", true);
        rs.updateRow();
      }
      conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return account;
  }
```

the loop prints the following

```
7223 id,  10001234567 phone_number,  1093629 account_id,  f used,  23:32:42.502472 local_time
```

accourding to the output above, then I am use that column "used" is part of the ResultSet. But I get the following Exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "used" of relation "account" does not exist
```

This is the query when printed

```
select phone_number.id, phone_number.phone_number, phone_number.account_id, phone_number.used AS used, (now() AT TIME ZONE account.timezone)::time AS local_time from account INNER JOIN phone_number ON account.id = phone_number.account_id where phone_number.used = false order by id DESC limit 1 for update
```

`used` belongs to the `phone_number` table not the `account` table. How can this be resolved?

Comment: I don't think you can update a ResultSet from a query with a JOIN

Comment: can you print the "String query" variable so that we can have more information how the query is look.

Comment: I have edited the question with the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the problem in your code:

```
rs.updateBoolean("used", true);
```

this statement will try to update the data of table through resultset but to do that you cannot user join and also there is one problem.
As you are updating via resultset it will try to update account table and if we find used column is account table then error occurs.

so your code is trying to find column "used" in account table but it is not there.

try this one:

```
String query = "select " + Stream.of(colNames).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
        + " from phone_number INNER JOIN account phone_number ON account.id = phone_number.account_id where phone_number.used = false order by id DESC limit 1 for update";
```